# Android >=5.0 MediaPlayer prepare fails

Tags: android, video-streaming, android-mediaplayer

I'm having an issue with MediaPlayer on devices Android SDK >= 21 with playing stream media (videos and audio in mp4/mp3).As excpected everything works fine for older devices.
I've searched some topics nad found it may be case of NuPlayer which is experimental replacement for AwesomePlayer but that doesn't solve my problem, even after changing it back to AP.

I'm stuck so I appreciate any help.

My code:

```
new AsyncTask() {

                @Override
                protected Void doInBackground(String... paths) {
                    if (mPlayer == null) {
                        mPlayer = new MediaPlayer();
                    } else {
                        mPlayer.reset();
                    }

                    if (mPlayer != null && mPlayer.isPlaying()) {
                        mPlayer.start();
                    }
                    String source = paths[0];


                    try {

                        mPlayer.setDataSource(source);
                        mPlayer.prepare();

                        mPlayer.start();
                    } catch (Exception e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                    return null;
                }
            }
```

My stack trace is as follows :

```
03-23 16:19:19.582: D/MediaPlayer(8241): Couldn\'t open file on client side, trying server side
03-23 16:19:53.902: E/MediaPlayer(8241): error (1, -2147483648)
03-23 16:19:53.905: D/MediaPlayer(8241): create failed:
03-23 16:19:53.905: D/MediaPlayer(8241): java.io.IOException: Prepare failed.: status=0x1
03-23 16:19:53.905: D/MediaPlayer(8241):    at android.media.MediaPlayer._prepare(Native Method)
03-23 16:19:53.905: D/MediaPlayer(8241):    at android.media.MediaPlayer.prepare(MediaPlayer.java:1125)
03-23 16:19:53.905: D/MediaPlayer(8241):    at android.media.MediaPlayer.create(MediaPlayer.java:866)
03-23 16:19:53.905: D/MediaPlayer(8241):    at android.media.MediaPlayer.create(MediaPlayer.java:839)
03-23 16:19:53.905: D/MediaPlayer(8241):    at android.media.MediaPlayer.create(MediaPlayer.java:818)
03-23 16:19:53.905: D/MediaPlayer(8241):    at myapp.FrameVideo$6.doInBackground(FrameVideo.java:609)
03-23 16:19:53.905: D/MediaPlayer(8241):    at myapp.FrameVideo$6.doInBackground(FrameVideo.java:1)
03-23 16:19:53.905: D/MediaPlayer(8241):    at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:288)
03-23 16:19:53.905: D/MediaPlayer(8241):    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:237)
03-23 16:19:53.905: D/MediaPlayer(8241):    at android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run(AsyncTask.java:231)
03-23 16:19:53.905: D/MediaPlayer(8241):    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1112)
03-23 16:19:53.905: D/MediaPlayer(8241):    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:587)
03-23 16:19:53.905: D/MediaPlayer(8241):    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:818)
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is my code and its working please try this

```
AssetFileDescriptor afd;
            // new music player object for new page
            mediaPlayerSound = new MediaPlayer();

        try {
            afd = getAssets().openFd("Audio/" + soundSource);
            mediaPlayerSound.setDataSource(afd.getFileDescriptor(),
                    afd.getStartOffset(), afd.getLength());

            mediaPlayerSound.prepare();
            mediaPlayerSound.start();

            mediaPlayerSound
                    .setOnCompletionListener(new OnCompletionListener() {

                        @Override
                        public void onCompletion(MediaPlayer mp) {
                            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                        }
                    });

        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
```